# Need information regarding OBD scanner

Tags: obd-ii

Can anyone help me with the query?
I want to know the difference between Basic and Advanced Fault codes in OBD2 scanner. Also want to know what are the fault codes comes under basic and advanced faults?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Comment: kindly edit your question to include more details and make it more specfic

Comment: This question would be more appropriate at the sister-site https://mechanics.stackexchange.com